# Select only most recent entries from database

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

My database collects member renewal information including the date of renewal (payDate). Active members are determined by the payDate column which must be later than 9-30 of the previous year to be considered active. The club allows a member to renew as early as October of the prior year. So a member that renews in October of 2015 is an active member through December 31 of 2016. The problem I have is during the months of October thru December if I build a table of active members, I will get many duplicate entries because the current renewal and the previous renewal are technically both active. For the purpose of reporting, I want only the most recent renewal.

My current query, which gives duplicates, is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM membership
INNER JOIN memberDues ON ID = memberID
WHERE payDate >= '$year-10-01'
ORDER BY lastName, firstName"
```

I've tried this alternate query which doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM membership
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(paydate) AS MAXpayDate
from memberDues)
memberDues ON ID = memberID
AND paydate = MAXpaydate
WHERE payDate >= '$year-10-01'
ORDER BY lastName, firstName
```

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT MAX(paydate)
FROM memberDues)
memberDues
INNER JOIN membership ON memberID = ID
WHERE payDate >= '$year-10-01'
ORDER BY lastName, firstName
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: post some sample datas of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get members that have paid after '$year-10-01' with most recent payDate.

```
select m.memberID, m.first_name, m.last_name, max(d.payDate) payDate
from   membership m
join   memberDues d on (d.memberId = m.id)
where  d.payDate >= '$year-10-01'
group by m.id, m.first_name, m.last_name;
```

**Update:**

To grab more column values from the member dues row.

```
select member_id, first_name, last_name, pay_date, amount, check_number from(
select member_id, first_name, last_name, pay_date, amount, check_number,
       case when @previous = member_id  then @rn := @rn + 1
            when @previous := member_id then @rn := 1
       end as rn
from   member m
join   memberDues md on (m.id = md.member_id)
join   (select @rn := 0) r
where md.pay_date >= '$year-10-01'
order by member_id, pay_date desc
) q
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks JRD - this technique was successful.

Comment: JRD: Just noticed: though the report displays the most current `payDate` from `membershipDues`, other fields such as `amount` and `check number` are reporting based on the older record. Any idea how fields from 2 different records would get blended?